# How to handle numbers that do not represent quantities

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

Here is my example:

I have a big store selling used cars.
I want to code a program that can predict car sales in future.
I want to use artificial neural network to analysis history data and solve this problem.
There are many years sales history.

Network Input:

- year of make
- manufacture
- color
- transmission
- miles
- price

(Just make it simple.)

Network Output: Days stay in market.

I found a problem very soon when I try to design the neural network.
Variables color, manufacture and transmission is different from other 3 variables.
Let's say there are 3 colors in total: white, black and red.
3 manufacture: Toyota, Ford and Benz.
3 transmission: manual, auto and CVT.

OK, since "color" is not a number, I cannot input "color" variable as integer.
Inputting it as a string also looks not like a good idea.
So, I decide to give every color an "id". White is 0, black is 1 and red is 2.
However, red is not twice as black and red is not closer to black than white...
Same problem to manufacture and transmission.

How can I let the neural network know this integer means an ID, not continuous numbers or quantities? Better with some simple codes.

Answer (score 3):

This is what we call **categorical** variables, and one of the typical method, which avoids the problem you described (red is not twice as black as black) is to use **one hot encoding**, so for a variable with K possible values you encode it as K-bit long binary representation, like:

```
v = {red, black, white}
```

leads to

```
red -> [1 0 0]
black->[0 1 0]
white->[0 0 1]
```

and so on. So you have binary, logical features "is this object red?" and so on.